# Have domain point to homeserver

Tags: home-server

I would like to point a subdomain of mine toy homeserver, which is accessible through my external ip. I've already added an A record and when I use curl it gives me the correct page. But when I visit it via my phone the connection times out. I'm using directadmin. Could I have configured something wrong?

Edit: It does not matter where curl is used. Using it from home or at work gives the same result.
I've investigated a bit more and it looks like my problems are being caused by my domain forcing https, because my webserver at home does not have https for testing purposes.

Comment: You don't specify where you are using `curl` from (i.e. what computer/IP) but if one device is allowed and one is blocked, this may mean that the server is set up to only allow certain connections (designated by IP(s)). So a local address (i.e. your PC) may be allowed but another address (i.e. your phone) may be blocked.

Comment: @anaksunaman added an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a .dev domain to point to a server without an SSL certificate. Which Google does not like. Appearantly they're forcing SSL/TLS for every .dev domain.

Answer (score 0):

If your `curl` command works from your LAN then it is possible (probable) that your ISP is blocking port 80 to incoming traffic.

It works on your LAN because the packet goes to your router and then right back to your network, and never reaches your ISP.

Comment: A friend of mine was also able to use curl from his pc to reach it, but not his browser.

Comment: @TheDutchman browser configured for proxy, etc. that wouldn't allow reaching it?

Comment: Mine isn't, and I don't think his is either. I can try my work laptop on monday. That one doesn't have a proxy for sure.